# Python - Custom tkinter - component.setfocus() don't work with customtkinter component like CTkEntry

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, customtkinter

I have this code and focus dont work with customtkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import customtkinter as ctk
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    print("Tk Customized from Tom")
    win = ctk.CTk()
    win.geometry("750x250")
    text = ctk.CTkTextbox(win, width=200, height=200)
    text.pack()
    text.insert(INSERT, "Hello World!")
    entry = ctk.CTkEntry(win, width=100)
    entry.pack()
    entry.focus_set()
else:
    print("Standard Tk ")
    win = Tk()
    win.geometry("750x250")
    text = Text(win, width=30, height=10)
    text.insert(INSERT, "Hello World!")
    text.pack()
    entry = Entry(win, width=30)
    entry.pack()
    entry.focus_set()

win.mainloop()
```

py testy.py   -> Start standard Tkinter  Focus is on Entry 
py testy.py 1 -> Start with customtkinter objects Focus is NOT on Entry

How can get focus on CTkEntry ?

Comment: It may be issue on `customtkinter`.  `focus_set()` works fine on `CTkEntry` after the window is visible.  So you can delay the calling `focus_set()` a bit using `.after()`: `entry.after(10, entry.focus_set)`.

Comment: Hi acw1668, thank you for work around, it work fine !