# CustomTKinter entry not getting focus

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I'm trying to set the focus to my entry but, it just doesn't work! I tried with normal TKinter and the focus_set method worked fine, any help plsss??

```
import customtkinter

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode('dark')  # Modes: "System" (standard), "Dark", "Light"
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme('green')  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue"

app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.geometry('220x155')
app.title('Program')
app.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')

frame_1 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=app)
frame_1.pack(pady=5, padx=5, fill="both", expand=True)

title = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame_1, text="Title", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight='bold'))
title.pack(pady = 1, padx = 1)

text = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame_1, text="Label", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=10))
text.pack(pady = 5, padx = 5)

entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame_1)
entry.focus_set()
entry.pack()


def imprime(event=None):
    print('txt')

def imprime2():
    print('txt2')

app.bind('<Return>', imprime)
ligar = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame_1, text='button', command = imprime2)
ligar.pack(pady=5, padx=5)

app.mainloop()
```

I want my window app to open and that my entry field gets de focus so I don't have to click it to start typing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74772739/python-custom-tkinter-component-setfocus-dont-work-with-customtkinter-com

Comment: @toyotaSupra I tried acw's .after solution and could not get it to work for me; however, I did find a solution that worked shown in the answer below.

Comment: Thanks for  solving problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're running into a timing issue, as in the widget hasn't been fully created when you try to give it focus.  Try this:

```
entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame_1)
app.update()
entry.focus_set()
entry.pack()
```

Comment: Nice! It works like a charm, ty very much! This .update() method does what exactly, I tried to find the info at the documentation but didn't find, may you have some link.

Sorry I cant upvote ur answer right now...

Comment: @MiltonVentura don’t have any link in particular - the need to update was something I’d run into before when I was dynamically resizing frames. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: Oh I see, nice to know I can use in that cases too, ty again.

Comment: That was very nice. I upvoted.

Comment: @Milton Ventura. TomSchimansky doesn't updated website..