# Tkinter focus_set() on Frame?

Tags: tkinter, customtkinter, python-3.11

I use Tkinter (actually customtkinter if it's important). What I need is a key bindings (escape, for example). It must to work differently in different frames, and in some frames I don't need it. I use frame system as some kind of tabs. Based on answers in other topics, I assumed that frames doesn't have key event bind by default, and ppl recommend to write
`frame.focus_set()` to be able to bind keyboard buttons. But this beautiful solution didn't help me. But the greatest mystery for me is why this example works fine:

```py
from tkinter import *

main = Tk()

def leftKey(event):
    print ("Left key pressed")

def rightKey(event):
    print ("Right key pressed")

frame = Frame(main, width=100, height=100)
frame.bind('<Left>', leftKey)
frame.bind('<Right>', rightKey)
frame.focus_set()
frame.pack()
main.mainloop()
```

And my code ignores the escape button: (alert! I know that my code style is awful, please no insult)

```py
class MainFrame(customtkinter.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, corner_radius=0, **kwargs)

'''some code'''

class WorldInfoFrame(MainFrame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        '''some code'''

        self.bind("<Escape>", self.wrapper_info_button_pressed)
        self.focus_set()
    
    @staticmethod
    def info_button_pressed():
        print("static")
        app.world_frame.info_button_released()

    '''some code'''

    def wrapper_info_button_pressed(self, event):
        print("Wrapper")
        self.info_button_pressed()
```

What is in the `app.world_frame.info_button_released()` doesn't matter, my code doesn't even prints "Wrapper". Well, I hope someone can help me or push me in the right direction...

Comment: maybe get working code and use `customtkinter.CTkFrame` to check if it will work with `CTkFrame`. Maybe all problem is `customtkinter`

Comment: I tested first code with `CTkFrme` and it doesn't work. I found similar question but about `CTkEntry` [Python - Custom tkinter - component.setfocus() don't work with customtkinter component like CTkEntry - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74772739/python-custom-tkinter-component-setfocus-dont-work-with-customtkinter-com) and it suggests to use `after()` to set focus when window is visible. But this doesn't work for me for `CTkFrame`. You may have to write to author(s) of `customtkinter` on [GitHub](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But the greatest mystery for me is why this example works fine:

I'm not exactly sure how to answer that, except to say it works fine because it is behaving as designed. Frames by default don't get keyboard focus, so by default they don't receive keyboard events. The code explicitly sets keyboard focus to a frame, so the frame receives keyboard events.

> ... And my code ignores the escape button:

The reason why the customtkinter code doesn't work is that customtkinter has some peculiarities in how it handles bindings. It unfortunately overrides `bind` to apply any bindings to a canvas widget embedded in the frame rather than the frame itself. So, the bindings get added to a canvas, but you set focus to the frame.

You can see this by changing your code to call `self._canvas.focus_set()` which will force the focus to be the inner canvas. Your bindings will then start to work.

I don't think this is a proper fix, but I'm not sure what the best fix actually is in this case. The customtkinter design doesn't make this clear. Maybe it's as simple as redefining `focus_set`, though I don't know what sort of side effects that might have.

```
class WorldInfoFrame(MainFrame):
    def focus_set(self):
        self._canvas.focus_set()
    ...
```

Comment: Yes! Works fine! It would be easier with clear and detailed CTk documentation. I wonder where I should search for this kind of info...

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the required part of the code alone. The most easiest approach for the same key working differently in different window is: Providing the binding information in the respective frame itself. For instance, if you want the enter key to work differently in each frame, in each frame provide bind command for that respective window. This won't uglify the code. Because understandability is more important than structure. for focus setting, I'll mention in the code itsel.

```
#create a function for focus set
def change_focus(wdg): wdg.focus_set()

#A function for what to do while pressing submit button
def submit_triggers(*event):
     <Do Something>

root = Tk()

#In root we bind enter key to focus in name_field
name = Label(root, text='Name')
name.pack(side='top')
name_field = Entry(root)
name_field.pack(side='top')
number = Label(text='Number')
Number_field = Entry(root)
Number_field.pack()

#in root frame we bind enter to focus in name_field widget
root.bind('<Return>', lambda x: change_focus(name_field))

#in the another frame called btm_frame, we bind enter key with submit button
btm_frme = Frame(root)
btm_frme.pack()
address = Label(btm_frme, text='Address')
address.pack()
addrss_field = Entry(btm_frme)
addrss_field.pack()

#Submit button triggers the function submit_triggers(*event)
submit = Button(btm_frme, text='Submit', command=submit_triggers)
submit.pack()

#in btm_frme, enter key is bound to submit button
#i.e enter key in this widget also should trigger the same function submit_triggers(*event)
btm_frme.bind('<Return>', submit_triggers)

root.mainloop()
```

A general question arises here is why do we provide an argument to the function submit_triggers i.e *event. Anyway the enter_key or the submit_button is going to trigger the function. Why should mention argument there?

Because the function is designed to be triggered by 2 events and not just one.So if we do not provide event argument, We'll get error for lesser number of arguments. Since the number of arguments is more than 1, we add * before the argument. (recollect *args)